# All decimals are removed after calling a function using double

Tags: c, function, printf, double

`printf` is removing the decimal places of my numbers. In my case both `6.9` and `6.4` print as `6.0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    double Value1_m, Value2_m;
    double maximum, minimum;
    printf("Enter two decimal numbers with an space: ");
    scanf("%lf" "%lf", &Value1_m ,&Value2_m);
    //printf("%3lf", Value1_m);

    maximum = ComputeMaximum(Value1_m, Value2_m);
    minimum = ComputeMinimum(Value1_m, Value2_m);

    printf("ComputeMaximum %.10lf\n", maximum);
    printf("ComputeMinimum %.10lf", minimum);
    return 0;
}

ComputeMaximum(double Value1, double Value2)
{

    return  (Value1 > Value2) ? Value1 : Value2;

}
ComputeMinimum(double Value1, double Value2)
{

    return  (Value1 > Value2) ? Value2 : Value1;

}
```

Comment: Your functions implicitly return `int`.  Explicitly return `double`, and turn on compiler warnings and declare or define functions before you use them.  The code you wrote has not been acceptable to a C compiler adhering to the current standard for the whole of this millennium.

Comment: `ComputeMaximum(double Value1, double Value2)` --> `double ComputeMaximum(double Value1, double Value2)`, also, use prototypes for your functions or include them before `main`

Comment: *Implicit int* seemed like a good idea at the time. Blame the Cantabrigian behind BCPL if you must. But luckily it was removed from the C standard in 1999.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after implementation is works as expected.

Comment: make a headerfile and declarations. life will be better for you.

Comment: That's not valid C. This coding style is outdated since more than 30 years.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite: point of pedantry — the C standard will be thirty years old next year (2019).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The C standard will be 8 years old by next year. What you mean is the first release. Nevertheless, omitting the return-type and using undeclared functions was discouraged even in K&R already (after all, the first revision of the standard had some discussion before its release).

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared return types for your `ComputeMaximum` and `ComputeMinimum` functions.  This is erroneous in modern C, and your compiler should be at least warning you.  Moreover, you are calling those functions at a point where the have no in-scope declarations.  This, too, is erroneous.

However, it used to be that if functions declared without a type were implicitly declared to return `int`, and that functions without in-scope declarations were assumed to return `int`, too.  A compiler that falls back to that behavior will accept your program, but the return values of those functions will be truncated to type `int`, and then the result converted back to `double` when you assign the values.

First, declare your function's desired return type.

Second, declare your functions before they are called, either by putting the complete definitions first, or by providing forward declarations:

```
double ComputMaximum(double, double);
double ComputMinimum(double, double);

// ...
```

Be sure that any forward declarations agree with the function definitions.

Comment: He doesn't necessarily have to declare the functions if everything is running for him right now. Although you are correct, it's a stupid move to not do so.

Comment: No, @ytpillai, C99 and later do not support implicit function or variable declarations.  The OP's code is *non-conforming* in this respect.  Moreover, a compiler supporting implicit declarations ala C90 and earlier will assume at the point of call that the functions return *`int`*, not `double`.  This is a mess that is unlikely to turn out well.

Comment: Now, I understood what you were saying. You are right, I'm wrong, my bad. Just wanted to add that OP probably has their declarations somewhere else and forgot paste it. Quite odd that they could run the entire program without those, unless they are working in C90 or something as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Printf is not the problem here, the problem is your functions themselves.

Look at this portion

```
ComputeMaximum(double Value1, double Value2)
{

    return  (Value1 > Value2) ? Value1 : Value2;

}
ComputeMinimum(double Value1, double Value2)
{

    return  (Value1 > Value2) ? Value2 : Value1;

}
```

You don't have a return type in these methods, meaning that the compiler doesn't know what's going to be given back with any finality. Whatever you are using is defaulting to returning an int, which as you have stated will result in getting rid of numbers after the decimal.

So essentially, the compiler reads it as this, adding a default return type.

```
int ComputeMaximum(double Value1, double Value2)
{

    return  (Value1 > Value2) ? Value1 : Value2;

}
int ComputeMinimum(double Value1, double Value2)
{

    return  (Value1 > Value2) ? Value2 : Value1;

}
```

You need to add a return type to these methods explicitly, so the default doesn't come into play.

```
double ComputeMaximum(double Value1, double Value2)
{

    return  (Value1 > Value2) ? Value1 : Value2;

}
double ComputeMinimum(double Value1, double Value2)
{

    return  (Value1 > Value2) ? Value2 : Value1;

}
```

Comment: And declarations of those functions also need to be in scope at the point of call.

Comment: Meh. It's compiling for him right now. I'm guessing he has the declarations somewhere. Maybe OP pulled a YOLO and edited stdio header file directly.

Comment: That it's compiling now without declarations is no more surprising than that it was compiling with implicit types for the functions at their definitions.  But after correcting that latter, implicit declarations assumed at the point of the function calls are suddenly *wrong*.  The behavior is probably *worse* with this half fix than the original behavior was.

Comment: Yes, I understood now, that's my bad, but OP probably has their declarations somewhere else and forgot to post it. Otherwise the fact that the program would give a partially correct output is weird.

Comment: No, I see no reason to think that the OP has function declarations elsewhere.  It is not particularly surprising that the program exactly as given would compile and produce the output described.  That's what one would expect from K&R C, for which many compilers provide backwards compatibility.  The implicit declarations assumed at the point of call are consistent with the later function definitions with implicit return types.

Comment: Forgot about the K&R compatibility. Yes that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Thanks to all ! This question has been answered!